# c# Linq - Is this a good design for deleting records?

Tags: c#, linq

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes a template data record
/// </summary>
/// <param name="RecordID">ID of the record</param>
public static void DeleteDataRecord(int RecordID)
{
    ArtworkingDataContext dc = new ArtworkingDataContext();

    // Delete associated datalabels
    var q = dc.tblArtworkDataLabels.Where(c => c.dataID == RecordID);
    dc.tblArtworkDataLabels.DeleteAllOnSubmit(q);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    // Delete the data record        
    var qq = dc.tblArtworkDatas.Where(c => c.ID == RecordID);
    dc.tblArtworkDatas.DeleteAllOnSubmit(qq);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Do I need to invoke deleteallonsubmit() twice, or can I have it just the once?

Comment: You should wrap your context in a using statement so it gets properly disposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach would be to have a FK relationship between `ArtworkDatas` and `ArtworkDataLabel` with a cascading delete set up in the DB - in that case you would not have to delete `tblArtworkDataLabels` at all, it would happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a FK relationship in my dbml file, do you have a resource on setting up cascading deletes?  This is basically what I am doing in code right?

Comment: you can do that in the DB directly, its hidden in one of the options for the FK relationship.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If so, in the FK property, there is a line that says "INSERT And UPDATE Specification"  you expand that and you can choose cascading delete.

Comment: Ah, I  guess I don't have my FK specified properly, I've just created an association in my dbml.  Thanks, I'll read more on it.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need two DeleteAllOnSubmit(...) calls, but only one Context.SubmitChanges().

I also suggest wrapping your context in a Using(...) clause.

```
public static void DeleteDataRecord(int RecordID)
{
    using(var dc = new ArtworkingDataContext())
    {
        // Delete associated datalabels
        var q = dc.tblArtworkDataLabels.Where(c => c.dataID == RecordID);
        dc.tblArtworkDataLabels.DeleteAllOnSubmit(q);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        // Delete the data record        
        var qq = dc.tblArtworkDatas.Where(c => c.ID == RecordID);
        dc.tblArtworkDatas.DeleteAllOnSubmit(qq);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

q and qq are not the same type of objects, so you'd have to call it twice, I believe.

You don't have to call dc.SubmitChanges() twice.

Additionally, you could set up your DB so that ArtworkData and ArtworkDataLabels are related with a cascading delete.  Then you could delete the primary and the secondary would be deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

### No, [Deleting Is Bad Design](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)